# Unable to install MySQL_python on OSX

Tags: python, django, macos

I am trying to use django with mysql. So in settings.py I gave the engine :

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

But when I try to run `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746863/django-manage-py-syncdb-throwing-no-module-named-mysqldb) I got the solution for it, i.e. to install MySQL_python. But when I try to install mysql_python I get the following error:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

All the solutions that I found suggest to install the new version of xCode. Is there a way to get rid of the error without installing xCode.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to install XCode to have `gcc` available in OS X, which is a requirement for compiling Python modules written in C.